# add facebook and google login in ionic2

Tags: angular, cordova, oauth, ionic2

I have try login with facebook and google with this example:

https://medium.com/appseed-io/third-party-authentication-for-your-ionic-2-mobile-app-9fdd43169deb

but I have this error :

[image]

and this is code error in js (after export code ts to js):

[image]

Comment: any help please ...

Comment: You will get better help by posting the code and not a screenshot.